# how to iterate over objects of objects and display in mustache template

Tags: node.js, express, mustache

I have the following data structure

```
{ 'the-subtle-art-of-not-givng-a-f': { "id: "test", "title": "test"}, "the-hamset": {"id": "test", "title": "test"}}
```

how can I display the title in a mustache template?

Comment: Iteration is not possible: [issue](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/issues/457). You might have to convert your data, as suggested in the issue I've linked.

Answer (score 0):

## jQuery

#### HTML:

```
<div id="output">

</div>

<script type="text/template" id="titles">
    <ul>
        {{#titles}}
            <li>{{title}}</li>
        {{/titles}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

#### JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const template = $('#titles').html();
    const output = $('#output');

    const object = {
        'the-subtle-art-of-not-givng-a-f': {
            "id": "test", "title": "test1"
        },
        "the-hamset": {
            "id": "test", "title": "test2"
        }
    };

    let titles = [];
    for (const property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (object[property].title) {
                titles.push( { title: object[property].title });
            }
        }
    }

    const data = { titles };

    const result = Mustache.render(template, data);
    output.append(result);
});
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/majestic84/pen/GRgJpgy)

---

## Vanilla JS:

#### HTML:

```
<div id="output">

</div>

<script type="text/template" id="titles">
    <ul>
        {{#titles}}
            <li>{{title}}</li>
        {{/titles}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

#### JS:

```
const callback = function() {
  const template = document.querySelector('#titles').innerHTML;
  const output = document.querySelector('#output');

  const object = {
    'the-subtle-art-of-not-givng-a-f': {
     "id": "test", "title": "test1"
    },
    "the-hamset": {
     "id": "test", "title": "test2"
    }
  };

  let titles = [];
  for (const property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      if (object[property].title) {
        titles.push( { title: object[property].title });
      }
    }
  }

  const data = { titles };
  const result = Mustache.render(template, data);
  output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + result;
};

if (
  document.readyState === "complete" ||
  (document.readyState !== "loading" && !document.documentElement.doScroll)
) {
  callback();
} else {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/majestic84/pen/GRggbNd)